# How do I use flvmeta to do the same af flvtool2 -U?

Tags: video, flv, video-processing, streaming-flv-video

We are currently using flvtool2 for flv video processing. I don't really know what it does, but i know we need the following command to run.

flvtool2 -U the_movie.flv

We are running into problems with large videos and have been searching for an alternative, and have found flvmeta, however it is not documented at all. We would like to use it, as it's in C (should beat ruby in performance) and claims it can handle large file easily.

Do you know the equivalent command options in flvmeta for the command stated above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using FLVmeta 1.0.x (the last version is 1.0.11) you have to use the following command line:

```
flvmeta input_file.flv output_file.flv
```

Using FLVmeta 1.1 (the last version is 1.1.0), which really should be used instead of the older 1.0 versions, you can use any of the following command lines:

```
flvmeta input_file.flv output_file.flv
flvmeta --update input_file.flv
flvmeta -U input_file.flv
flvmeta -U -m input_file.flv (will display injected metadata)
```

Each of these invocations will update the **input_file.flv** file with computed metadata including keyframe information, just like flvtool2.

The full FLVmeta manual can be found at https://flvmeta.com/flvmeta.1.html.

Comment: Buy this man a drink! Thanks Sir Darius, this sorted me right out. You really deserve to have your answer accepted for that one.

Comment: i don't deserve much merit, being that i'm flvmeta's author ;)